# Force HTTPS on all pages except one

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a WordPress site that I want fully secured using SSL, with the exception of one page (it has a third party script who will not serve over SSL - let's say it's called /booking/), I also want all URL's redirected to the www version.

I've seen similar answers for the other way around, but not this specific use case.

Is this achievable using .htaccess?

Edit:

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN Custom
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^00\.00\.00\.00
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^((?!online-booking).*) https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [NC,L,R,NE]

</IfModule>
# END Custom
```

*real IP replaced with zeros, this is to redirect the server IP to the actual website.

This code is for the page being at mysite.co.uk/online-booking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^00\.00\.00\.00
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /online-booking [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/online-booking [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work. Would you mind explaining why a 302 has been used here as opposed to a 301?

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
 RewriteEngine on


#--Redirect non-www or http requests excluding "/booking" to https--#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^((?!booking).*) https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't appear to be working unfortunately. If I remove the "s" then it allows me to browse the whole site over http, if I try https on the "booking" url, then it also allows it.

Comment: @User319940 Try clearing your browser's cache. for me the code is working fine on apache.

Comment: I've just tried this but still doesn't work, could it be that other rules are stopping it from working? I'll update the question with the full htaccess file